# Python pandas flag matching values in column in one dataframe to column in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, match

I just spent an hour on stackoverflow looking for a similar question, so please excuse if this has been asked before and I didn't find it.

I have the following dataframe df:

```
  Id | Category | Subcategory | Count | Flag | Phone_number
  1       A           aa        4534     Y      222-444-3333
  2       B           bb        4807     Y      3335557777
  3       C           cc        8978            222-444-3333
  4       D           dd        9874            333-555-7777
  5       E           ee        3187            555-666-8888
  6       F           ff        8573            5556668888
```

The column "Flag" indicates established incorrect records. Now I need to flag/highlight all records that have the same phone number, even though they don't have a flag.

First, I need to take out all the "-" from Phone number, since it has been entered by users.

```
df['Phone_number'] = df['Phone_number'].str.replace('-', '')
```

(not sure this is the best way)

Next, I couldn't think of a better way to approach it then create a new df of records with the Y flag and without the Y flag.

```
new_df = df.loc[df['Flag'] == 'Y']
df_withoutY = df.loc[df['Flag'] != 'Y']
```

But now I am stuck. How do I compare/match the phone number in df_withoutY and if it does exist in new_df, add a new column "incorrect" = "Y".

I was thinking of something like this, but get all False.

```
df_withoutY['Phone_number'].isin(new_df['Phone_number'])
```

This didn't work at all:

```
df_withoutY['incorrect'] = np.where((df_withoutY['Phone_number'].isin(new_df['Phone_number'])) == True, "Y" " ")

TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Not sure, if this is helpful, but in excel, I would have split the two into two separate tabs by Flag and then used the Match function.

```
=MATCH(df_withoutY!AK2,new_df!AK$2:AK$3395,0)
```

Once I do that, I was planing on merging the two dfs back together, but now having the new column "incorrect". If there would be an approach without splitting dataframes that would be even better.

This is the end goal df:

```
  Id | Category | Subcategory | Count | Flag | Phone_number | incorrect
  1       A           aa        4534     Y      222-444-3333
  2       B           bb        4807     Y      3335557777
  3       C           cc        8978            222-444-3333      Y
  4       D           dd        9874            333-555-7777      Y
  5       E           ee        3187            555-666-8888
  6       F           ff        8573            5556668888
```

Thank You

Comment: when I have a chance, I'll take a deeper look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [219]: phones_normalized = df.Phone_number.str.replace('-','')

In [220]: df['incorrect'] = \
     ...: np.where(phones_normalized.isin(df.loc[df.Flag=='Y', 'Phone_number'].str.replace('-',''))
     ...:          & (df.Flag!='Y'),
     ...:          'Y',
     ...:          '')
     ...:

In [221]: df
Out[221]:
   Id Category Subcategory  Count Flag  Phone_number incorrect
0   1        A          aa   4534    Y  222-444-3333
1   2        B          bb   4807    Y    3335557777
2   3        C          cc   8978       222-444-3333         Y
3   4        D          dd   9874       333-555-7777         Y
4   5        E          ee   3187       555-666-8888
```

alternatively you can "reuse" your `Flag` column:

```
In [226]: df.loc[df.Phone_number.str.replace('\D+','').isin(df.loc[df.Flag=='Y', 'Phone_number'].str.replace('\D+','')), 'Flag'] = 'Y'

In [227]: df
Out[227]:
   Id Category Subcategory  Count Flag  Phone_number
0   1        A          aa   4534    Y  222-444-3333
1   2        B          bb   4807    Y    3335557777
2   3        C          cc   8978    Y  222-444-3333
3   4        D          dd   9874    Y  333-555-7777
4   5        E          ee   3187       555-666-8888
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas.merge on the phone number column in each data frame:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

You can do an outer join and then use the df.loc functionality which you already know.

Just make sure you preprocess the phone numbers in the same way before the join so that they are the same format and data type.

Comment: So sorry - but I don't understand, why I would merge the two dataframes that I just split - I need to establish a way to match the phone numbers in the one dataframe to the phone numbers in the other dataframe

Comment: If you merge them back together and create a new data frame, that will match the phone numbers in the two data frames.